# Upload Button No Display Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, sweetalert

I am using sweet alert alongside c# asp.net. For my download and delete button, the sweet alert display managed to be displayed when the user clicked the button. For the upload button, i wanted that the code will check if the file uploaded by the user was empty or not. If it was empty, then a message ("No file uploaded") and if it was not empty ('File was uploaded successfully").

```
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="fileUpload" />
 <script>
                $('#fileUpload').click(function (e) {
                    if ($('#fileUpload').val() === "Upload") {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Nothing',
                            text: 'No file selected',
                            type: 'error',
                            confirmButtonText: 'Again!!',
                            timer: 4000

                        })                     
                    }
                    if ($('fileUpload').val() !== "Upload") {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Wait awhile...',
                            text: 'File will be uploaded shortly',
                            type: 'success',
                            confirmButtonText: 'Okay, cool',
                            timer: 4000
                        })
                    }

                });
            </script>
```

However, when i click on the upload button, neither of these pop-up messages are displayed. What am I missing out? I have reupdate my code. Now only the second message is displayed whenever i clicked the upload button. I want if the upload button is click to check for the existence of the file and if yes, the second message will be displayed, otherwise the first message will be displayed.

Comment: Not sure what your trying to accomplish here, but `#fileUpload`'s value is "Upload", you set it in the html yourself. Try  `if ($('#fileUpload').val() === "Upload")`

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools is an effective tool for figuring out these kinds of things.

Comment: Does not work either. @mxmissile. It had no difference. I am not sure how to verify if there is a file uploaded or not.

Comment: I have reupdated my code. Kindly check

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fileUpload').val() // always get 'Upload'
```

Use `document.getElementById('file').files` or `$('#file')[0].files` to check if any file selected.

Comment: $('#file')[0].files would replace $('#fileUpload').val() === "Upload")? is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify if the input has any file.

Try this:

```
$('#fileUpload').click(function (e) {
  if (this.files.length > 0)
  {
    swal({
      title: 'Wait awhile...',
      text: 'File will be uploaded shortly',
      type: 'success',
      confirmButtonText: 'Okay, cool',
      timer: 4000
    });

  }
  else
  {
    swal({
          title: 'Nothing',
          text: 'No file selected',
          type: 'error',
          confirmButtonText: 'Again!!',
          timer: 4000
        });
  }
});
```

Comment: Now , no popup message is displayed when i clicked on the upload button

Comment: Have you tried the popup message? According to the documentation sweet alert it calls using only swal({}) removing the 'fire' method https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Comment: Yes, in my original code, there was popup but it was only the second message will popup when i click upload irregardless of whether there was a file uploaded. i copy pasted your code but there was still no popup. even when i write swal()

Comment: Check the console maybe it's another error, check references

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
            $('#fileUpload').click(function (e) {
                if ($('#file').val() === "") {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Nothing',
                        text: 'No file selected',
                        type: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Again!!',
                        timer: 4000

                    })
                }
                else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Wait awhile...',
                        text: 'File will be uploaded shortly',
                        type: 'success',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Okay, cool',
                        timer: 4000
                    })
                }

            });
        </script>
```

So i managed to get it working with this code block. I tried swal without fire but there was no pop-up message still. My concern now is that when there is no file selected, the message does pop-up but only a brief while like a second, not like what I wanted the timer to be